# Delete multidimensional array by a specific key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this multi-dimensional array and I want to delete completely if the `[earnings]` index are empty.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [earnings] => 
        [other] => Array()
        [ord] => 2
        [days] => 1
        [total] => 1
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [earnings] => The campaign was effectively ended in November 1917.
        [other] => Array
        (
            [campaign] => 1
            [novemb] => 1
            [today] => 1
        )
        [ord] => 1
        [days] => 8
        [total] => 1
    )
)
```

I like to output something like this:

```
[1] => Array
(
    [earnings] => The campaign was effectively ended in November 1917.
    [other] => Array
    (
        [campaign] => 1
        [novemb] => 1
        [today] => 1
    )
    [ord] => 1
    [days] => 8
    [total] => 1
)
```

I tried this but not doesn't work quite well:

```
 foreach($array as $key=>$test){

 foreach($test as $koval=>$user) { 

      if( empty($user['earnings']) || !file_exists($staff['earnings'])) {
          unset($array[$key][$koval]); }}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping 1 too many times. What you want is this:

```
foreach($array as $i => $item) {
    if(empty($item['earnings'])) {
        unset($array[$i]);
    }
}
```

[**Example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/5dlpV7)

---

*You should look at FuzzyTree's answer below for a cleaner way of doing this.*

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array_filter($array,function($item) {
    return (!empty($item['earnings']));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `array_filter` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'earnings' => null,
        'other'    => array(),
        'ord'      => 2,
        'days'     => 1,
        'total'    => 1,
    ),
    array(
        'earnings' => 'The campaign was effectively ended in November 1917.',
        'other'    => array(
            'campaign' => 1,
            'novemb'   => 1,
            'today'    => 1,
        ),
        'ord'      => 1,
        'days'     => 8,
        'total'    => 1,
    ),
);

var_dump($arr);
//array(2) {
//    [0] =>
//    array(5) {
//        'earnings' =>
//        NULL
//        'other' =>
//        array(0) {
//        }
//        'ord' =>
//        int(2)
//        'days' =>
//        int(1)
//        'total' =>
//        int(1)
//    }
//    [1] =>
//    array(5) {
//        'earnings' =>
//        string(52) "The campaign was effectively ended in November 1917."
//        'other' =>
//        array(3) {
//            'campaign' =>
//            int(1)
//            'novemb' =>
//            int(1)
//            'today' =>
//            int(1)
//        }
//        'ord' =>
//        int(1)
//        'days' =>
//        int(8)
//        'total' =>
//        int(1)
//    }
//}
$filtered = array_filter($arr, function ($val) {
    return isset($val['earnings']) && !empty($val['earnings']);
});
var_dump($filtered);
//array(1) {
//    [1] =>
//    array(5) {
//        'earnings' =>
//        string(52) "The campaign was effectively ended in November 1917."
//        'other' =>
//        array(3) {
//            'campaign' =>
//            int(1)
//            'novemb' =>
//            int(1)
//            'today' =>
//            int(1)
//        }
//        'ord' =>
//        int(1)
//        'days' =>
//        int(8)
//        'total' =>
//        int(1)
//    }
//}
```